# This can / could be explained

Tags: modal-verbs

> This **can** be explained by ..
>
> This **could** be explained by ..

Are these two interchangeable or do they conform to different situations?

Let's take for example the following two sentences:

> All available classification schemes for internet trolls are incomplete. This **can (could)** be explained by the fact that the species is evolving rapidly.

Will both *can* and *could* look OK here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Can*** makes a stronger statement, implying the speaker's belief in the correctness of the given explanation.

***Could*** is much weaker, merely offering up a possibility.

Either one may certainly be used in that example, but there is a definite difference of meaning.

Comment: I agree, "could" really says: "It is possible that this is an explanation". Where "can" is much closer to "It *is* an explanation"